# Algorithm for testing correct operation of the UNPKBU4 instruction on TMS320C66x

Tags: testing, assembly, instructions, microprocessors

algorithm on testing the correct operation of the UNPKBU4 instruction in the TMS320C66x microprocessor.

I hope someone here point me to the right direction cause I am kinda stuck and I need some guidance if possible if it a course or steps to be taken anything I have about one month to do so, thanks in advance

I searched online and I found out that assembly is the language needed I believe other than that I can't say for sure

Comment: Generally, you will feed the tested instruction with random input data and compare its result with the expected value. However, in the [TMS320C62x Instruction Set](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru731a/spru731a.pdf) there is no such instruction UNPKBU4.

Comment: thanks a lot, so generally I can apply this concept to any TMS processor
by the way it was TMS320C66x

Answer (score 1):

I have constructed test frameworks for various instruction sets in the past, such as x87, MMX, 3dNow!, and SSE.

The way to do this is to construct a golden reference in the form of emulation code written in C or C++, then generate test vectors to compare the responses from the golden reference to the hardware for these inputs.

According to the [TMS320C66x DSP CPU and Instruction Set Reference Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sprugh7) the `UNPKBU4` instruction performs the straightforward expansion of four packed bytes into four packed 16-bit half-words using zero extension, and it shows in section 3.415 how that works in detail. You can create a function `uint64_t unpckbu4_ref (uint32_t x);` as the reference based on that specification. Note the use of fixed-width integer types.

You should be able to access the hardware instruction via the `_unpkbu4()` intrinsic listed in table 8-4 of the [TMS320C6000 Optimizing Compiler
v8.2.x User's Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sprui04b/sprui04b.pdf). Inspect the generated machine code to make sure this actually invokes the `UNPKBU4` instruction. Alternatively, there *may* be ways of accessing the instruction via inline assembly, or by linking to a separately compiled wrapper function written in assembly code that utilizes the instruction. I wrote "may" because I have not used this particular platform, but these alternatives are generally available on *most* computing platforms.

What remains is to generate test vectors for eliciting responses from both the hardware instruction and the golden reference model. A generic technique is to use *random numbers* generated with a good quality PRNG (pseudo-random number generator). This by itself is suitable for a quick "smoke" test that establishes that the functionality is not completely broken. For single-input operations with a 32-bit input, such as `UNPKBU4`, correct operation can be demonstrated by an *exhaustive test*, i.e. applying all possible 2<sup>32</sup> inputs, and I highly recommend this. It will take only a few minutes.

For operations with more input bits, for which exhaustive test is not feasible, it is important to check corner / edge cases. For example, for the `UNPKBU4` instruction each byte should take the minimum and maximum values of `0x00` and `0xff` and to make sure the extension is by zero-extend rather than sign-extend, each byte should also take the values of `0x7f` and `0x80`.

For an initial test run, you would follow-up on any mismatches to resolve them based on the instruction specifications. You would either correct the golden reference and / or the test framework, or correct the hardware in cases where that is still under development, e.g. when creating a new CPU implementation, or clarify the specification itself if necessary. Thereafter you should be able to carry forward the golden reference code for new generations of processors.

Comment: thank you for your time and effort I will try to implement your solution and go back to you with the result