# Testing instruction implementation on QEMU

Tags: c, testing, cpu-architecture, qemu, instructions

I've extended the QEMU-based instruction set of a specific architecture using helper functions. How do I go about testing their implementation? Are there any standard QEMU testing practices or do I just use a debugger like gdb?

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of [Algorithm for testing correct operation of the UNPKBU4 instruction on TMS320C66x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75930464) re: procedures for testing a single instruction.